# CryptoAPI - how to extract RSA public key from private

Tags: rsa, public-key-encryption, cryptoapi, encryption-asymmetric

Using windows CryptoAPI, is it possible to get public RSA key from a private key which was imported (not generated)?

If I use CryptGenKey, I can call CryptExportPublicKeyInfo and CryptImportPublicKeyInfo to obtain the public key handle. However, when I try to do the same thing with private key decoded from PEM and imported using:

```
CryptImportKey(hCSP, pKeyBuf, cbKeyBuf, 0, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE, &hPrivKey)
```

import of the private key succeeds and I have a valid handle but the subsequent call to CryptExportPublicKeyInfo fails with "Key does not exist" error. It looks like there's another call missing between CryptImportKey and CryptExportPublicKeyInfo, but I can not find that API call.

Comment: What does your `CryptExportPublicKey` call look like? Is it a signature key or a key encryption key?

Comment: The PEM being imported was generated by calling CryptExportKey(hKey, 0, PRIVATEKEYBLOB, 0, &buf, &size) and buf then encoded into DER -> PEM. I can successfully import private key from the PEM but don't know how to get public key out of it.

Comment: I'm talking about the "subsequent call" that fails, not the origin of the private key. Does the second export look the same as the original export? I am not familiar with the CryptoAPI, but other APIs that I know well offer an API to give you a "transparent" view of key material. In the case of an RSA private key, that would generally give you a structure representing the key in Chinese Remainder Theorem form (CRT), which would have a number of large integer members. I didn't see anything like that skimming quickly over the Windows CryptoAPI docs. Does that ring a bell?

Comment: Thanks for your interest in this question, I figured it out (see the [code](https://gist.github.com/aleks-f/21d8ebf5547e17e71c92)) and I'm able to move on with work but it is still not 100% clear to me why CryptExportPublicKeyInfo()/CryptImportPublicKeyInfo() does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with exporting/importing the public key was because private key was generated using AT_SIGNATURE, instead of AT_EXCHANGE. See the [explanation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.platformsdk.security/N-Mo8jga4_8) and the [example code](https://gist.github.com/aleks-f/21d8ebf5547e17e71c92)